# inheriting a list to use it's in-place sort method

Tags: python, sorting, mmap

I'm trying to sort the contents of several files (sometimes moving a line from one file to another)

I would like to use the built-in adaptive merge sort that is and attribute of `list`.  I tried inheriting the method from `list`, but I don't know if it needs more than `__len__`, `__getitem__`, and `__setitem__`.  Yes.  I want to sort in-place.

FYI, Here is my code so far (if it helps explain what I am doing)  the order is not changed when I call .sort().  If i add my own bubble_sort method written in python, it works, but is terribly slow:

```
class Memwrap(list):
    def __init__(self, prefix, folder='.', chunksize=None):

        fns = [fn for fn in os.listdir(folder) if fn.startswith(prefix)]
        fns.sort()
        self.files = [open(os.path.join(folder,fn), 'r+') for fn in fns]
        self.mmaps = [mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0) for f in self.files]
        self.sizes = [mm.size() for mm in self.mmaps]
        if chunksize is None:
            self.chunksize = len(self.mmaps[0].readline())
        else:
            self.chunksize = chunksize


    def _mm_from_idx(self, idx):
        bidx = self.chunksize*idx
        lo = 0
        for m,s in zip(self.mmaps, self.sizes):
            hi = lo + s
            if lo <= bidx < hi:
                return bidx-lo, m
            lo = hi

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        bidx, mmap = self._mm_from_idx(idx)        
        return mmap[bidx:bidx+self.chunksize]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
        assert len(val) == self.chunksize
        bidx, mmap = self._mm_from_idx(idx)
        mmap[bidx:bidx+self.chunksize] = val

    def __len__(self):
        assert not sum(self.sizes)%self.chunksize
        return sum(self.sizes)/self.chunksize


    def bubble_sort(self):
        for i in xrange(0, len(self) - 1):
            swap_test = False
            for j in range(0, len(self) - i - 1):
                if self[j] > self[j + 1]:
                    self[j], self[j + 1] = self[j + 1], self[j]  # swap
                swap_test = True
            if swap_test == False:
                break
        self.flush()


    def flush(self):
        for mm in self.mmaps:
            mm.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.flush()
        for mm in self.mmaps:
            mm.close()
        for f in self.files:
            f.close()
```

Comment: You can't sort the contents of a file in place AFAIK.  It sounds to me like you'd need to read the contents as a list of lines, sort the list of lines, and then truncate the file and re-write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual list sorting code is available here (around line 2000): https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

As far as I can tell, it would not be possible to use that code with a different storage mechanism.

You can make your sorting algorithm faster (using quicksort, etc.) or use the ctypes module to interface with a C-based sorting algorithm (e.g. http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/lib/sort.c).

Finally, you could use the linux sort application to sort the data (using the subprocess module if you wish to control it in Python).  `sort filea fileb filec` will likely be faster than anything you can do in Python, mmap or not.

Answer (score 1):

The sort method of lists is written in C (in CPython) and so does not need to use `__getitem__` and _`_setitem__` methods at all. If it did use those methods it would slow the normal list.sort() down immensely

You may be able to store the file indices in a list and use list's builtin sort with a `key` function to do some of the work for you

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what inheriting from `list` does.

Your `Memwrap` isn't just getting the `list` interface it **is** a list (which is an in-memory structure like an array of Python objects that can't be directly expressed in Python). You then add a bunch of additional instance members, and override some `list` methods to talk to your members instead of the normal `list` instance data (because you never actually call the base class implementations). Note that `Memwrap` still has the instance data inherited from `list`, but as far as the data is concerned it remains an empty list with a bunch of attributes tacked on.

It happens that a lot of the operations on builtin types are implemented in C and just use the C-level data directly rather than going through the Python level hooks (like `__getitem__`). So while this sort of inheritance-to-get-the-interface can work for Python level classes (although it's a hack really), it usually doesn't for builtin types. It's certainly not what you're "supposed" to do with subclassing builting types; it's more expected that you make a `list` that works slightly differently (you can add defaults, extra methods, meta-data, etc) than that you make a completely different thing that shares an interface. For that, see the ABCs in the `collections` module.

I don't see how you can use `list`'s builtin sort without actually having a `list`. Memory mapped files are supposed to be faster than doing tons of little OS-level calls, but to sort you're essentially reading in and rewriting the entirety of all the files anyway, so I can't see how you'd get it to go faster than doing just that; read in all the files into memory, sort them, and then write out the results to the files.

Your trick of using mmaps to do an inplace sort files containing fixed-size chunks of data is quite clever, but you'd really have to be using C all the way to actually get it to work and be fast. Python doesn't have an operation for an inplace file sort (it's a pretty obscure operation, since it's impossible unless you assume the data chunks are some fixed-size), you can't get `list`'s sort to do it for you, and implementing such a sort yourself in Python is bound to be slower than a good C implementation. That said, it should be an IO bound operation, not compute bound, so are you **sure** it's actually possible to do the job *much* faster than your bubble sort?

Comment: I have to sort about 10G maybe as much as 100G of data.  Loading into memory is not an option.  The files are already fairly well sorted and I estimate something less than 10% of the files get re-written.  The data chunks are guaranteed to be fixed-size at 40 bytes.  The Linux `sort` command is much much faster than any pure-python sort implementation.  However, I was reaching for OS-agnostic solution.  Thanks for your help.  I didn't realize this was a "hacky" way of inheriting.

Comment: @Paul Then using memory mapped files looks like a good approach, but you'll have to implement the sort yourself. I call this kind of inheritance "hacky" becuase you're not really implementing a special new kind of list, just its interface. True, you *were* trying to inherit the implementation of sort, but most classes have to be specifically designed to have a method like that work when you completely divorce it from the original class internals (and that's usually only true of abstract classes, because those classes don't *have* specific internals until you create a subclass to supply them).